# Colorization of BASH script output with tput - how to select good colors?

Tags: bash, shell-script, colors, user-interface, tput

I would like to colorize output of one long complex interactive `BASH` script to make it easier for the user to work with it. I [have learned how to use tput](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_tput.php), but my question is more matter of design:

Terminal style is usually `whitish background` and `black text`, or `black background` and `white/yellow/light green` text. If I need then, lets say, **three** colors for my script, how to choose them to look good on any terminal?

I have seen once even terminal with `pink background with white snowflakes` and `black text`... Well, I could explicitly set black background and colorize output as I wish, but **I don't wish to overwrite user's settings**.

Is there any general advice how to deal with that?

Comment: Maybe first pick *bad* colors - like light yellow and dark brown - and print two messages to the screen at the start of the script. Print one message in yellow and the other in brown. Make one say "Press SPACEBAR to continue" and the other should ask for the ENTER key. Whichever key is pressed is almost definitely the one which the user was more easily able to read.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that best practice is not to try and find colors that work with all backgrounds, but to adapt to the current background. This is e.g. the default for vim highlighting schemes, which have "light" and "dark" variants. You can [read the background color from the environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507337/is-there-a-way-to-determine-a-terminals-background-color) and choose your colors accordingly: Use light colors if the background is dark, and dark if the background is light.

Comment: The referenced page reports some issues, so that I wonder how reliable the detection of background is... Otherwise it is interesting idea.

Comment: If you are using xterm, the control sequence is reliable.  If you are not, there is the less-reliable convention of environment variable.  Environment variables can be inherited...